# Wireless driver needs to be recompiled after each kernel upgrade

Tags: wireless

I have a D-Link DWA-125 Wifi USB key, which I managed to get running via this tutorial:
http://kaustav.codebinders.com/2011/10/install-dwa-125-wireless-driver-on-ubuntu-11-10.html

The only problem I have is that every time I upgrade the kernel I need to rebuild and re-enable the module.

Is there any way around this?

I am currently running 12.04 (I did have the same issue with the 11.10 release).

Answer (score 2):

Did you compile it with DKMS ? It's normal to have to recompile a module after a kernel update, module compiled with DKMS are automatically recompiled at each update.

Comment: No it was not compiled with DKMS from what I can see. I will have a look around and see if I can figure out how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, if it works, don't forget to check answer ;-)

Comment: Hmm a little more complex than I anticipated; when I am trying to compile I am getting a weird error: ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for dwa125-wireless-driver: 1.0 not found
Error!  Build of rt5370sta.ko failed for: 3.2.0-22-generic (x86_64)
From what I can see the files are there (but bare in mind I did not know what DKMS was a couple of hours ago :) )

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I can't leave the comments but can only answer here:)
I had the same problem with installing my card(rt2870). All I had to do is to rename the binary file(the one that ends with .ko) in the `../os/linux` to the one that is missing and after that I run `build` again without any issues.